# grayscale filter not working in android phone default browser

Tags: android, html, css, svg

i have written the grayscale for a image in ccs using the below css

```
img.grayscale {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

img.grayscale:hover {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

It is working fine in my desktop browser. But in my android phone, tablet it is not working in default browser. working in firefox browser.

Comment: Working in new android version 4.4.2.

Comment: filter support was added to Android in 4.4

Comment: ok thanks for your info. is there any other way to display images with grayscale in lower version. i have checked in chrome browser for android 4.4.2 and lower version its working. but its not working in any android version with the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

refer this source https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/blob/master/demo.html. It works in all devices..